# After updating Azure Powershell module cannot import my module anymore and getting strange error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I just updated to the latest Azure powershell but after that I can no longer import my module (worked fine for a very long time). This is the error that I am getting:

> Import-Module : Method 'get_DataCollectionWarning' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.GetAzureAutomationCertificate' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + im .\MyResources.psd1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], TypeLoadException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Can someone please suggest what may be going on wrong here. Note that the method without implementation seem to be from the Azure PS package.

Comment: What is the module you are trying to import? Is it a standard Azure PowerShell module or it's your own PowerShell module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have upgraded your Azure PowerShell to version **5.0.0**, it is a **BREAKING CHANGE RELEASE** based on its [release notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v5.0.0-November2017).

You should refer to see the [migration guide](https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide) for a full list of introduced breaking changes.

In addition, the Azure PowerShell team has also released a newer version **5.0.1** which fixed the issue which might also related to your problem.

> Fixed assembly loading issue that caused some cmdlets to fail when
>   executing in the following modules:
>
> - AzureRM.ApiManagement
> - AzureRM.Backup
> - AzureRM.Batch
> - AzureRM.Compute
> - AzureRM.DataFactories
> - AzureRM.HDInsight
> - AzureRM.KeyVault
> - AzureRM.RecoveryServices
> - AzureRM.RecoveryServices.Backup
> - AzureRM.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery
> - AzureRM.RedisCache
> - AzureRM.SiteRecovery
> - AzureRM.Sql
> - AzureRM.Storage
> - AzureRM.StreamAnalytics

Hope this helps.